# Sending signed S3 URL to browser with node express

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

My express app is generating a signed S3 URL on the server. The URL works fine and loads the file when I copy and paste it in the browser.

Ideally I would like to have the app bring up the save/open dialog in the browser.
I have tried various express responds:

This prepends the local file path to the URL and throws an error: `Invalid path`

```
res.download(s3_url);
```

I can see the URL is being send to the browser but nothing else

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='myFile.jpg');
res.send(s3_url);
```

No errors but nothing happens here either:

```
res.attachment(s3_url);
```

This one throws an error: `TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='myFile.jpg');
res.sendFile(s3_url);
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!